# White button SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `SLComposeViewController` to post tweets from within my app.  However, the 'Cancel' and 'Post' buttons seem to be white and I cannot find a way to change them back to the default blue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Default color of Cancel and Post is blue so i don't understand what is your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have probably changed the main `UIWindow`'s tint color to white. Looks like the `SLComposeViewController`'s view is added as a subview of the main window (and inherits the tint color).